# how to get changed files from TFS using nant

Tags: configuration, tfs, scripting, nant, ccnet-config

It is really painfull to get all code form TFS whenever you make a build using NANT.
Is there any settings in ccnet.config which will only take the files which are changed form last time which can speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

The "get" process will only actually download files that are different than the version in the workspace, unless you are specifying a /force which will force it to get the specified version even if TFS thinks it has that version in the workspace.

Comment: But still after taking out this, it is still checking out all the files.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually getting them?  It will show all files being processed, but it should only be actively getting the ones that aren't up to date.

Comment: Im seeing all the files dated at the time of build.So you mean that the date won't change if build won't take latest or even then it says dated it didn't get it from TFS?

Comment: The dates should only change on those files that have been "gotten" from TFS.  If you have build date/time on all files then you are right, it is still getting everything.  The only reasons TFS will do this is if you have /force turned on, or TFS's record of the file that is in the current workspace shows that it isn't the latest.